# continue on assert

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Is there any way to continue test after Assert? .. I need to see all cases which the assert causes.

```
foreach (var ex in data)
{
     Assert.AreEqual(ex1, ex, msg);
}
```

Comment: It's common guidance to only include one Assertion per test. It would be best to actually split up this test into a tests for every item in your `data` collection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't - `Assert` will throw an exception if it fails, and you can't just keep going after the exception. You *could* catch the exceptions, and then add them into a collection... but it's not terribly nice.

If you're trying to basically test several different cases, most modern unit test frameworks have ways of parameterizing tests so that each case ends up as a separate test, with separately-reported pass/failure criteria. We don't know which framework you're using or what the different cases are here, but if you could give more context, we could try to help more...

Answer (score 4):

`Assert.AreEqual` throws assertion exception. So, you can't simply move to next assertion. You should catch them, but that's not how assertions supposed to be used. Failed assertion should stop test execution.

So, you should have single assertion which will return all required data for you. If you want verify that all items are equal to some value, then you should write it in test. If test fails you can dump all collection to error message or just items which are not expected (I used [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) for that):

```
Assert.IsTrue(data.All(ex => ex == ex1), 
              JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.Where(ex => ex != ex1)));
```

In case of fail this assertion will serialize all items to JSON and show them in test runner message. E.g. if you have collection of integers:

```
var data = new List<int> { 1, 1, 5, 1, 2 };
int expected = 1;
Assert.IsTrue(data.All(i => i == expected), "Unexpected items: " +
              JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data.Where(i => i != expected)));
```

Test will fail with message:

> Assert.IsTrue failed. Unexpected items: [5,2]

Answer (score 2):

You could catch the exception, add it to a list, then continue. At the end, you could assert that the list is empty.

Comment: But its not a good practice to do this. You should either create a separate test for each scenario you are testing or use parameterized tests.

Answer (score 1):

That article explains how to 'Verify' your value.
[Adding verify to MsTest](https://web.archive.org/web/20120415013652/http://www.havecomputerwillcode.com/blog/?p=888)

Comment: That link is dead. This is eactly why link only answers are frowned upon -- now the reader is left with the information that you *had* a solution, but it's lost now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio and the `data` you are talking about is just test data and not an actual collection of your program, you can feed the test data to your test method in the following way:

```
[TestMethod()]
[DataRow("1", "2")]
[DataRow("2", "3")]
[DataRow("3", "4")]
public void TheTest(string str1, string str2) {
    Assert.AreEqual(str1, str2);
}
```

This way, each data case is treated as a separate test and is thus non-aborting.
However, the output in Visual Studio may not be as compact as you like.

For this reason, I suggest building your own error message while looping the test data, where each fail is separated by a newline. If, at the end, you `Assert.Fail()` that full message, the Test Explorer window will list all the failed elements quite nicely, separated by a new line.

```
string errors = "";
[TestMethod()]
public void TheTest(...){
    data.ForEach( if(wrong) errors += "\n it's wrong");
    if(errors != "")
        Assert.Fail(errors);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently was trying to do this for comparing to test files with file HASH strategy. This worked for me. **FileAssert.AreEqual** method return true or false in this case.

```
 var equal =  FileAssert.AreEqual(manifest.FileContents, storedFile);

                if (!equal)
                {
                    var fileText1 = Encoding.Default.GetString(manifest.FileContents);
                    var fileText2 = Encoding.Default.GetString(storedFile);

                    var dmp = DiffMatchPatchModule.Default;
                    var diffs = dmp.DiffMain(fileText1, fileText2, true);
                    var html = dmp.DiffPrettyHtml(diffs);
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(AssemblyDirectory, APP_DATA, "ManifestTestErrors.html");
                    File.WriteAllText(filePath, html);
                    Assert.False(!equal, $"Check {new Uri(filePath).AbsoluteUri} for more info");
                }
```