# Unit testing in VS2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I want to test my code on some data set. This is the list of files that can be updated by some users in my company. I use unit testing run before build release and don't know is testing data set is updated now. I use Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting. Now I write code like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
     foreach (var src in testDataSetFiles)
     {
           Assert.IsNotNull(someMethodForTest(src), "fail");    
     }
}
```

When the assert is triggered unit testing is stopped for Test1. Its as it works, I know. But maybe there is a way to continue test runs after some `src` is failed? I don't want to write separate TestMethod for every `src`. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [continue on assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872747/continue-on-assert)

Comment: You might want to look into data test methods or parameterized tests and using the `testDataSetFiles` as the data source.

Comment: Simply convert your test case to parameterized, https://blogs.msmvps.com/bsonnino/2017/03/18/parametrized-tests-with-ms-test/

Answer (score 0):

Assert will throw an exception. You should have a test for each case you want to test.

That said, there are ways to do what you want. You can count how many times it fails:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    int nFails = 0;
    foreach (var src in testDataSetFiles)
    {
        if (someMethodForTest(src) == null)
        {
            nFails++:
        }
    }

    Assert.IsTrue(nFails == 0);
}
```

Or you can do a try-catch and add the exceptions that the Assert gives in a list and check it in the end.

Comment: That's too low efficiency, and you don't know which data set file fails.

Comment: Info can be added depending on what is being tested. That said, saving all exceptions will have a worse performance but will tell everything (or so I think) that you might need to know.

Comment: Check my comment above. There are far better ways.